# I have a bunch of words (strings?) in an ArrayList and I'd like to know if I can find the size of each element?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, size

So like the title says: I have a bunch of words in an ArrayList and I want to know how I can get the size of each element in the ArrayList. For example:

```
ArrayList input = new Arraylist();
input = {"Hello", "Goodbye", "Segall", "Ty"};
```

Id like to know if there is a way to find out the length of the first element which, in this case, would be "Hello". I had something in mind like:

```
 input(0).size();
```

That obviously doesn't work.
I also tried setting up variable for it like this:

```
String variable = input.get(0);
variable.length() or variable.size();
```

But turns out-- input is an object and variable is expecting a string type.
I am a beginner to this so if this stupidly easy question I apologize!

Comment: This code won't even remotely compile. Are you using an array, or a list? Have you read _any_ of the JavaDocs for the classes/methods you're using (`List`, `String`, etc.)?

Comment: @MattBall - apparently that's only for showing the values. OP has used the `add` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either typecast your object coming from the list like this`(String)input.get(0);`

or make your array list declaration like this

```
ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<String>(); // Preferred way.
```

So that you don't need a cast.

And finally you can call `variable.length()` to get the length.

Comment: I did use the add method in my main code. I just did that to show a quick example. And Im going to try the typecast

Comment: typecase is not a good approach, if you are sure that your array list is gonna contain only `Strings`. Use the other method specified. `ArrayList<String>`.

Comment: @EricJablow - `ArrayList<>()` is supported in java 7 itself.

Comment: Don't learn bad habits. Use the typed declaration. In fact, write it as List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>(); declare variables as interfaces when possible. And if you use Java 7, you can use new ArrayList<>() on the right side. (Edit of a deleted comment.)

Comment: @R.J  Could you explain why adding <String> to the end of ArrayList allows me to use the .length() method on variable? Is it because I am stating that the elements in the ArrayList will be of the String type?

Comment: @MaCo - Yes! that's the reason. If you don't specify anything, by default, `ArrayList` will treat that variable to be of the type `Object` and `Object` doesn't have the `length()` method.

Comment: `get(index)` - returns the type of object as specified while declaring the `ArrayList`. Hence, if you specify `String` there, the `get(index)` will return a `String` object. In case, nothing is specified, it'll be treated as `Object`. The reason why you could insert a `String` even though you didn't specify `String` is because `String` extends `Object`.

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, you don't specify that it is an array list of `String`. When declaring the array list, you want to use

```
ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then for each element you want to add, use

```
input.add("myString");
```

Comment: Suppose we get past the stage of initializing and adding elements.

Comment: Never mind I think I have this figured out thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Check this-

```
    final List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>() {
        {
            add("Hello");
            add("Goodbye");
            add("Segall");
            add("Ty");
        }
    };

    for(String word : input) {
        System.out.println(word + " --> " + word.length());
    }
```